# How do I avoid my JSON request becoming a Nonetype?

Tags: javascript, python, json, post, axios

I am trying to build a Post route from a JS front-end to a Python back-end. This is what I have so far:

```
    async submitScore(){
    await axios({
        url: 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/submit',
        method: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify({"score": game.score}),
        contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
    });
    console.log(data)
}
```

and

```
def submit_score():
    data2 = request.form.get('data')
    data = request.get_json()
    print (data, data2) # returns NoneNone
    return 'hello'
```

When I try to also pass force=True into request.get_json(), it sends me a 400 error. I can't understand why, because to me it seems like I'm sending json data? Could anybody point me in the right direction? Thank you

Comment: I don't think you need to do `JSON.stringify()` to send the data. Send it as object without stringify

Comment: I just tried that, Today, it did not work.

Comment: Whoa! Something just changed. I changed my axios post request to look like: await axios.post('url', {"score": game.score} and it went through! I am curious if anybody understands why I was getting my error, though? It seems like the original post request was formatted correctly. Anyone?